# How to differentiate bettween .ai and .eps file in Android

Tags: java, android, google-drive-android-api, android-googleapiclient

I'm having trouble to differentiate bettween .ai and .eps file ... Actually I was trying to get actual MIME type from Google drive with extention !!!

Google drive gives response `application/postscript` for both .eps file and also for .ai file as MIME type as extention !!! While I was trying to download and save the file into my app .

Kindly give any solutions if you have, or else let me know if you have any dobuts regarding the same .

Thanks in advance .